Reconciling disparity between test-accuracy and confusion matrix in tensorflow
Update: it's definitely something going on with the the predict function using a custom generator. When I fetch all the test data in one batch and run predictions on it, then create a confusion matrix between predictions and labels, I get what I expect for accuracy which is around 90%. I still need help though - because what if I wasn't able to fetch all the test data at once? Suddenly I have no solution. And I don't see why using a data generator to fetch in smaller batches shouldn't work
I'm trying to make an image classifier on the COVID-19 Radiography Dataset, specifically a binary classifier that predicts whether an lung-image is from the COVID group or Normal group. I wanted to make use out of the lung-masks that are included in this dataset, so I applied the masks to the lung-image through component-wise multiplication batch by batch using a custom data generator
My code appears to work fine, except that the accuracy result I get from testing (around 91% accuracy) wildly disagrees with what I see on the confusion matrix (using both scikit and tf) and by manually printing accuracy using scikit (around 62%) accuracy.
Furthermore, the last step of my code displays 100 predictions. Every time I run that, I come up with around 9 fp+fn and the rest are accurate predictions, which appears to agree with the output accuracy from model testing.
I looked online for potential solutions and frequently people say "shuffling" in the data generator may be a source of the issue, but even after commenting out shuffling for the entire process, I got the same result. Now I have shuffle on during training and off during testing.
If someone can look at my work and help me understand this disparity as well as help me get to understanding the true accuracy of my model, that would be amazing.

https://www.kaggle.com/code/dawsonkimyon/lung-image-binary-classification-sandbox
the data generator
def custom_generator(image_paths, mask_paths, labels, batch_size=32, shuffle=True): 
    num_samples = len(image_paths) 
    while True:  # Infinite loop for Keras generators 
        indices = np.arange(num_samples) 
        if shuffle: np.random.shuffle(indices)    
    
        for start in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
            end = min(start + batch_size, num_samples)  # Correctly handle the end index
            batch_indices = indices[start:end]  # Select the indices for this batch
            
            # Diagnostic prints
            """
            print(f"Generating batch: {start // batch_size + 1}")
            print(f"Start index: {start}, End index: {end}")
            print(f"Number of indices in this batch: {len(batch_indices)}")
            """
            batch_images = []
            batch_labels = []
            
            for idx in batch_indices:
                img_path = image_paths[int(idx)]
                mask_path = mask_paths[int(idx)]
                
                # Load and process the image and mask
                image = Image.open(img_path).convert("L")
                mask = Image.open(mask_path).convert("L")
                mask = mask.resize((299, 299), Image.LANCZOS)
                
                image_array = np.array(image) / 255.0
                mask_array = np.array(mask) / 255.0
                
                multiplied_image = image_array * mask_array
                
                # Expand dimensions to add a channel
                batch_images.append(np.expand_dims(multiplied_image, axis=-1))
                batch_labels.append(labels[int(idx)])
            
            yield np.array(batch_images), np.array(batch_labels)  

#the model evaluation
test_generator = custom_generator(test_image_paths, test_mask_paths, test_labels, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)


test_steps = (len(test_image_paths))  
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_generator, steps=test_steps)

print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy * 100:.2f}%")
print(f"Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}")


test_predictions = model.predict(test_generator, steps=test_steps)

predicted_classes = (test_predictions > 0.5).astype("int32")


test_generator = custom_generator(test_image_paths, test_mask_paths, test_labels, batch_size=1)


#cm, accuracy from cm, and manual accuracy

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels, predicted_classes)


print("Confusion Matrix:")
print(cm)

cm_accuracy = np.trace(cm) / np.sum(cm)
print(f"Accuracy from Confusion Matrix: {cm_accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

manual_accuracy = accuracy_score(test_labels, predicted_classes)
print(f"Manually Calculated Accuracy: {manual_accuracy * 100:.2f}%")


Does the accuracy from the confusion matrices change if you run the prediction part again? This would indicate some kind of randomness. On first look, your generator should be deterministic.

It produces the same confusion matrix - yet for some reason the whole thing works when I load the data in one "batch" which still has me convinced there is something going on between the predictions and the labels being desynchronized. This is a problem because of memory allocation limitations. I was able to get it all loaded in one batch - now I'm running out of memory when I try to do it. Also I don't want to depend on being able to do it in one batch.
